# Matching similar string vectors and return non-matching element

Tags: r, string

I have 2 datasets containing similar string vectors (product titles). The only difference between the strings in both datasets is absence/presence of special characters.

Now, my problem is to match the corresponding string vectors and return the non-matching element(s) (which should be special character(s) in each case). There can be many non-matching special characters in a single string.

For e.g. I have 2 texts:

```
Text 1: Analog Science Fiction and Fact February 1995
Text 2: Analog Science Fiction and Fact, February 1995
```

Is there an R function to return the non-matching element(s) only?

This is how I approached the problem

```
S.vector <- strsplit(Acceptdata['Text.1'][1,],' ')
S.vector
# [[1]]
# [1] "Analog"   "Science"  "Fiction"  "and"      "Fact"     "February" "1995"    

F.vector <- strsplit(Acceptdata['Text.2'][1,],' ')
F.vector
# [[1]]
# [1] "Analog"   "Science"  "Fiction"  "and"      "Fact,"    "February" "1995"

l.S.vector <- tolower(S.vector)
l.F.vector <- tolower(F.vector)
grep("l.S.vector",l.F.vector,invert=T,value=T)
# [1] "c(\"analog\", \"science\", \"fiction\", \"and\", \"fact,\", \"february\", \"1995\")"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

When I'm trying to run the algorithm for the entire dataset(~500 vectors) its throwing an error as is.character(a) is not TRUE.

The procedure I followed:

```
common <- function(a,b) { 
  for (i in seq_along(a)) 
    for (j in seq_along(b)) 
    i2 <- strsplit(tolower(i),'') 
    j2 <- strsplit(tolower(j),'') 
    if(length(i2) < length(j2)) { 
      i2[(length(i2)+1):length(j2)] <- ' ' 
    } else if(length(i2) > length(j2)) { 
      b2[(length(b2)+1):length(a2)] <- ' ' 
    } 
    LCS(i2,j2) 
} 

z <- common(a,b) 
Error: is.character(a) is not TRUE
```

Any idea on where did I go wrong?

Comment: You need `{}` brackets around your `for`-loops. E.g., `for(i in seq_along(a)) { for(j in seq_along(b)) { ... }}`.

Comment: In your loops `i` is a number (i.e., the position in the sequence of numbers from 1 to the length of object `a` and object `b`). Thus `strsplit(tolower(i))` is something like `strsplit(tolower(1))`, `strsplit(tolower(2))`, etc. at each iteration of the loops. You probably want something like: `strsplit(tolower(a[i]))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm totally clear on your intended output, but I think this will help you get there. It uses the `LCS` function from the **qualV** package.

```
library("qualV")
common <- function(a,b) {
    a2 <- strsplit(a,'')[[1]]
    b2 <- strsplit(b,'')[[1]]
    if(length(a2) < length(b2)) {
        a2[(length(a2)+1):length(b2)] <- ' '
    } else if(length(a2) > length(b2)) {
        b2[(length(b2)+1):length(a2)] <- ' '
    }
    LCS(a2,b2)
}
```

Here's an example using your two strings:

```
a <- 'Analog Science Fiction and Fact February 1995'
b <- 'Analog Science Fiction and Fact, February 1995'
z <- common(a,b)
paste0(z$LCS, collapse = '') # common string
# [1] "Analog Science Fiction and Fact February 1995"
z$b[which(!seq(1,max(z$vb)) %in% z$vb)] # non-matching elements in `b`
# [1] ","
z$a[which(!seq(1,max(z$va)) %in% z$va)] # non-matching elements in `a`
# character(0)
```

Here's an example using two strings that have more differences:

```
a <- 'Analog! SCIENCE Fiction and Fact Feb. 1995'
b <- 'Analog Science Fiction & Fact (February 1995)'
z <- common(a,b)
paste0(z$LCS, collapse = '') # common string
# [1] "Analog S Fiction  Fact Feb 1995"
z$b[which(!seq(1,max(z$vb)) %in% z$vb)] # non-matching elements in `b`
# [1] "c" "i" "e" "n" "c" "e" "&" "(" "r" "u" "a" "r" "y"
z$a[which(!seq(1,max(z$va)) %in% z$va)] # non-matching elements in `a`
# [1] "!" "C" "I" "E" "N" "C" "E" "a" "n" "d" "."
```

Comment: Really appreciate your elaborate reply. Unfortunately, I'm getting this error message                               z$f[which(!seq(1,max(z$vf)) %in% z$vf)]
Error in seq.default(1, max(z$vf)) : 'to' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite
In addition: Warning message:
In max(z$vf) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

Comment: Moreover, I'm also getting                        paste(z$LCS,collapse='')
[1] "AnalogScienceFictionandFebruary1995" unlike your result for the common string ('Fact' & 'Fact,' missing as they are not common in both strings)

Comment: `f` is not an element of the return value of `LCS`. Take a look at `str(z)` to see what elements you can extract. The vectors are always called `a` and `b` in the `LCS` return value.

Comment: For your second question, what exactly are you using as input to `common` to get that result?

Comment: I have named the strings as 's' & 'f'. So, do I have to rename them as 'a' & 'b'? For the 2nd question, I'm using the exact function called out by you except that I have renamed the strings.      common <- function(s,f){
+ s2 <- strsplit(s,' ')[[1]]
+ f2 <- strsplit(f,' ')[[1]]
+ if(length(s2) < length(f2)) {
+ s2[(length(s2)+1):length(f2)] <- ' '
+ } else if(length(s2) > length(f2)) {
+ f2[(length(f2)+1):length(s2)] <- ' '
+ }
+ LCS(s2,f2)
+ }              attach(Acceptdata) # name of my dataset
> z <- common(s,f)
> paste(z$LCS, collapse = '') [1] "AnalogScienceFictionandFebruary1995"

Comment: You don't need to rename them. Just when you want to look at the results, they're always going to be `z$a` and `z$b`. What exactly do `s` and `f` look like?

Comment: I have just renamed the same Text 1 and Text 2 as 's' & 'f' (as per the variable names in my dataset)                                  s <- 'Analog Science Fiction and Fact February 1995'               f <- 'Analog Science Fiction and Fact, February 1995'

Comment: Code is working perfect. Wanted to convert both the strings to lowercase. Working perfect in conjunction with tolower() as well    a2 <- strsplit(tolower(a),'')[[1]]
b2 <- strsplit(tolower(b),'')[[1]]

Comment: Just a quick question. When I'm trying to run the algorithm for the entire dataset(~500 vectors) its throwing an error as is.character(a) is not TRUE. The procedure I followed:        common <- function(a,b) {
+ for (i in seq_along(a))
+ for (j in seq_along(b))
+ i2 <- strsplit(tolower(i),'')
+ j2 <- strsplit(tolower(j),'')
+ if(length(i2) < length(j2)) {
+ i2[(length(i2)+1):length(j2)] <- ' '
+ } else if(length(i2) > length(j2)) {
+ b2[(length(b2)+1):length(a2)] <- ' '
+ }
+ LCS(i2,j2)
+ } z <- common(a,b) Error: is.character(a) is not TRUE. Any pointers on this?

Comment: @Debbie Can you edit that into your question? It's hard to read as a comment.

Comment: I have included my last comment in the question

Comment: Getting the same error with repeated attempts :( Updated the question with my latest attempt

Comment: Probably the algorithm is not able to identify that each datapoint is a 2-tuple (a1,b1), (a2,b2) and so on. Each i has to match only its corresponding j. For each i, its trying to match all the j's in b and that's where its running into an error (just an assumption). Tried another variant but still not working out.