# Match string of words and return non-matched words

Tags: r, string

I would like to match a string of words between two columns and return the unmatched word.

Example data frame:

```
data = data.frame(animal1 = c("cat, dog, horse, mouse", "cat, dog, horse", "mouse, frog", "cat, dog, frog, cow"), animal2 = c("dog, horse, mouse", "cat, horse", "frog", "cat, dog, frog"))
```

I would like to add a new column "unique_animal", with the resulting data frame:

```
                 animal1           animal2 unique_animal
1 cat, dog, horse, mouse dog, horse, mouse           cat
2        cat, dog, horse        cat, horse           dog
3            mouse, frog              frog         mouse
4    cat, dog, frog, cow    cat, dog, frog           cow
```

I have tried the code from this question: [Matching similar string vectors and return non-matching element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945196/matching-similar-string-vectors-and-return-non-matching-element)

```
library(qualV)
common <- function(a,b) {
  a2 <- strsplit(a,'')[[1]]
  b2 <- strsplit(b,'')[[1]]
  if(length(a2) < length(b2)) {
    a2[(length(a2)+1):length(b2)] <- ' '
  } else if(length(a2) > length(b2)) {
    b2[(length(b2)+1):length(a2)] <- ' '
  }
  LCS(a2,b2)
}

result <- NULL
data$animal1 <- as.character(data$animal1)
data$animal2 <- as.character(data$animal2)
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  data_temp <- data[i,]
  z <- common(data_temp$animal1,data_temp$animal2)
  paste0(z$LCS, collapse = '') # common string
  x <- z$a[which(!seq(1,max(z$va)) %in% z$va)] # non-matching elements in `a`
  x <- paste(x, collapse='' )
  data_temp$unique_animal <- x
  result <- rbind(data_temp, result)
}
```

Which produces this:

```
                 animal1           animal2 unique_animal
1 cat, dog, horse, mouse dog, horse, mouse         cat, 
2        cat, dog, horse        cat, horse         , dog
3            mouse, frog              frog       mouse, 
4    cat, dog, frog, cow    cat, dog, frog             ,
```

The commas aren't a problem, I can easily remove them. But it doesn't work when the non-matching word is at the end of the string. For some reason it doesn't count the total number of elements in this case. Any ideas how to alter this code so it doesn't do this? Or an alternative method?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After splitting the columns at `,\\s*`, we can use `map2` to do the comparison between corresponding `list` elements with `setdiff`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
data %>%
   mutate(unique_animal = map2_chr(strsplit(as.character(animal1), ",\\s+"), 
                 strsplit(as.character(animal2), ",\\s+"), 
             ~ str_c(setdiff(.x, .y), collapse=", ")))
#                 animal1           animal2 unique_animal
#1 cat, dog, horse, mouse dog, horse, mouse           cat
#2        cat, dog, horse        cat, horse           dog
#3            mouse, frog              frog         mouse
#4    cat, dog, frog, cow    cat, dog, frog           cow
```